# Repeating background not filling container div with relative absolute position with percentages

Tags: css, position

I'm using a page with relative & absolute positioning and percentages. HTML & Body are set to 100%, the container div is relative and the interior divs are absolute. The repeating background image I've set to the container div is not filling the page - it's stopping part way down why? Thanks in advance!

Here's what I've got:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body { 
width:100%;
    height:100%;}

.container {
   width:1000px;
   height:100%;
   background-image:url('background.jpg');
   position: relative;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
  }
.header {
   width:1000px;
   height:300px;
   background-color:#ffffff;
   position: absolute;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
  }


.content {
   width: 680px;
   position:absolute;
   top: 350px;
   left: 310px;
  }

.post {
   width: 630px;
   padding: 20px;
   padding-top: 50px;

  }

.title {
   width: 650px;
   height: 20px;
   padding: 10px;
   position: absolute; left: -10px; top: 10px;
  }




</style>

<body>
<div class="container">

 <div class="header">
 Placeholder for header image.
 <p><a href="index.html">Home</a></p>
 </div>


 <div class="content">
  <div class="post">
   <div class="title">Welcome</div>

    <img src="PLACEHOLDER.JPG" alt="Proposal Photo" width="630" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It might help if you also posted the HTML

Comment: It's there, after the closing style tag. Is it not visible?

Comment: I see it now, the page didn't load fully on my browser. Issue on my end.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want? [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/leoMestizo/Hjvt3/)

Just add this CSS rule in the `div.container` element

```
background: url('Your URL') repeat;
```

As you can see, I used the shorthand property.

BTW, just add the `height` in the `html` and `body` to 100% (you'll obtain the same result that adding the `height` and `width` properties).

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It seems it should work but the repeating background image only fills up a portion of the screen and I'm not sure why not....

Comment: Because you have made the layout with `position` property.

Comment: I understand why the background wouldn't fill up the whole width of the screen, but the  container div is set to 100% height so shouldn't the repeating background image fill up the entire height of the browser window?

Comment: Yes, but a good layout don't do it setting specific height, width and with position properties. Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/leoMestizo/Hjvt3/1/) (to give an example).

Comment: I wish I understood this better! I see the example, but it's still not what I'm aiming for, which is a repeating background image only filling up the container div which itself, is 100% height and only part of the width of the screen. I really appreciate your time though!